# Fluentbit parse json

Tags: json, elasticsearch, logging, fluent-bit

I'm using fluentbit to parse logs. I have logs in next format:

```
{"key1":"value1","key2":"{\n \"date\": \"2021-07-05 13:58:20.501636\",\n    \"timezone_type\": 3,\n    \"timezone\": \"UTC\"\n}", "key3":"{ \n \"somedata\": \"somevalue\" "}
```

In ES and Kibana I get something like that:

```
key1: value1
key2: {
        date: 2021-07-05 13:58:20.501636
        timezone_type: 3
        timezone: UTC
      }
key3: {
        somedata: somevalue
      }
```

So, some fields parsing, but I want to parse all fields, like

```
key1: value1
key2.date: 2021-07-05 13:58:20.501636
key2.timezone_type: 3
key2.timezone: UTC
key3.somedata: somevalue
```

using fluentbit config:

```
[FILTER]
    Name parser
    Parser api
    Match *
    Reserve_Data On
    Reserve_Key On
    Key_Name log
    Merge_Log  on
    Merge_JSON_Key log
[PARSER]
    Name   api
    Format json
    Time_Key date
    Time_Format %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%u
    Time_Keep On
```

I tried to decode fields with `Decoders` like `Decode_Field_As    escaped     log` but nothing, log writing in same format.

Answer (score 1):

### Two potential issues:

1. The issue could be with the **FILTER** that is being used. Instead of `Merge_JSON_Key log` try `Merge_Log_Key log_processed`. *Note we changed the value to be `log_processed` too*

   ```
   [FILTER]
       Name parser
       Parser api
       Match *
       Reserve_Data On
       Reserve_Key On
       Key_Name log #Not sure if this is necessary??
       Merge_Log  on
       Merge_Log_Key log_processed
   ```
2. If that doesn't work then its probably data related. The json data is being sent to logs as a `string` object rather than `json` by the look of things.

Check my other answer here which explains how we solved a similar issue: [How to split log (key) field with fluentbit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71707240/how-to-split-log-key-field-with-fluentbit/73059700#73059700)

Answer (score -1):

You should use `Decode_Field_As    json     log` in place of `Decode_Field_As    escaped     log`

It will decode the JSON into different fields in kibana.