# How to split log (key) field with fluentbit?

Tags: elasticsearch, filebeat, opensearch, fluent-bit, fluent-bit-rewrite-tag

We are sending node.js code to OpenSearch using FluentBit. We are having issues because *log* key contains nested value as *message*. We need to split the values mentioned in the below log message -

```
log-    {"level":"info","message":"\"{\"method:\" GET , \"url:\" / , \"status:\" 404 , \"responseTime:\" 0.545 ms , \"responseContentLength:\" 39}\"\n","timestamp":"2022-04-01T12:48:37.091Z"}
```

We need to split each and every field as separate -

level: info
method: GET
status: 404

Answer (score 1):

We had a similar problem and there was two parts to the solution:

1. **Add Kubernetes filter in the Fluent-bit config file**
2. **Correct the json logging from our APIs/microservices**

Though your issue looks json format related, specifically for the `message` field (*see point 2 below*)

---

**1. Add Kubernetes filter in the Fluent-bit config file**

```
  ## https://docs.fluentbit.io/manual/pipeline/filters
  filters: |
    [FILTER]
        Name kubernetes
        Match kube.*
        Merge_Log On
        Merge_Log_Key log_processed
        Keep_Log Off
        K8S-Logging.Parser On
        K8S-Logging.Exclude On
```

Now this splits the json output in new fields:

- `log` = "{original dict as string}"
- `log_processed.level` = "info"
- `log_processed.message` = etc.

---

**2. Correct the json logging from our APIs**

It looks like the `message` field in your json is outputting as a `String`, not a `json` object.

i.e. you have:

```json
{
  "level": "info",
  "message": "\"{\"method:\" GET , \"url:\" / , \"status:\" 404 , \"responseTime:\" 0.545 ms , \"responseContentLength:\" 39}\"\n",
  "timestamp": "2022-04-01T12:48:37.091Z"
}
```

But you may want this instead:

```json
{
  "level": "info",
  "message": {
    "method": "GET",
    "url": "/",
    "status": "404",
    "responseTime": "0.545 ms",
    "responseContentLength": 39
  },
  "timestamp": "2022-04-01T12:48:37.091Z"
}
```

*Please note that I've assumed datatypes here to demonstrate the issue only.*

---

Some relevant reading/links:

- https://docs.fluentbit.io/manual/installation/kubernetes#log-files-overview
- https://docs.fluentbit.io/manual/concepts/data-pipeline/filter
- Helm chart configs - https://github.com/fluent/helm-charts/blob/main/charts/fluent-bit/values.yaml